# Update if disabled = 0 in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I am making a project in `C#`- in which one can "vote".

When you run the program you first log in. After you've logged in you have to select a value out of a dropdownlist. After you've selected the teacher you press on a button which votes.

The problem is I don't really know how to let this validate properly. And to check if the person has already voted.

It has to check the column in the database named "disabled" if the value = 1 or 0. If the value = 1 they can't vote and if it's 0 they can.

When the person votes it increases the column `aantalStemmen` by 1. and the `disabled` column to 1 aswell. Which gets shown in a datagridview.

And the values in the dropdownlist has to match the 1 in the database.

I have this code:

```
 private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=docent;Integrated Security=True";
            connect = new SqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private bool validate_disabled(string favoriet)
    {
        db_connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select disabled from leerling";
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        SqlDataReader disabled = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (disabled.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }



    private void btnStem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string favoriet = cmbFavoriete.Text;

        db_connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        bool r = validate_disabled(favoriet);

        if(r){

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE docent SET aantalStemmen = aantalStemmen + 1 where docentid=@id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cmbFavoriete.Text);
        }
        else
        {
MessageBox.Show("You have already voted.");
        }

    }
```

my tables in my database looks like this:

[image: Table leerling]

[image: Table Docent]

Thanks in advance, I've been struggling really hard with this as I'm still a rookie in C#.

Comment: (not related to your problem) Don't open a connection and keep it around. `SqlConnection` is optimized for short lived connections inside `using` blocks that get created and disposed of quickly due to the [Connection Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) it uses underneath. Also you should be putting your `SqlCommand` and `SqlReader` in `using` blocks also.

Comment: _`"Select disabled from leerling"`_ - this gets all disabled fields from all students. You need to add a `where` defining which student you want to check

Comment: Ah thats true I have to do a WHERE query on the logged in person. Do you know how I can do that @Wimmel ?

Comment: If a person logs in, you need to store somewhere who is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try an answer to cover more aspects of your code (many already mentioned in comments):

**1) Declare your connection string outside of your methods.** Also choose meaningful variable names - you will than yourself in a few months when you revisit the code.

```
private const String ConnectionStr = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=docent;Integrated Security=True";
```

**2. Appropriate names for methods** - also, try to use [Camel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) or Pascal case for method names.

**3. Pay attention to possible exceptions.** `SQLException` is [not the only possible exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) when constructing or opening an SqlConnection, so it is better to catch anything that might occur

```
private SqlConnection createConnection
{
   try
    {
        connect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr);
        connect.Open();
    }
    // this is laziness, but it is better than before 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // best to log the real error somewhere
        throw;
    }
}
```

**4. Dispose connection and other disposables like SqlCommand**. Also var might save some typing (just hover your mouse over the keyword and you will see the actual type).

SqlConnection allows to directly create a command to be executed using that particular connection by using [CreateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx).

Since your are expecting a single value (scalar) (or a single row with a single column), you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So, no more reader.

```
private bool isDisabled(string favoriet)
{
    using (var connection = createConnection())
    {
        using (var cmd = new connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select disabled from leerling where leerlingnummer = @number";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", favoriet);

            // for simplicity I have assumed that it will always find a value. This should be checked
            var disabled = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return disabled;
        }
    }
}
```

**5. Try not to mix UI logic with database logic** (they are usually put in different assemblies)

```
private void castVote(String favoriete)
{
    using (var connection = createConnection())
    {
        using (var cmd = new connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE docent SET aantalStemmen = aantalStemmen + 1 where docentid = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cmbFavoriete.Text);
            // command must be actually executed, otherwise nothing happens
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private void btnStem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string favoriet = cmbFavoriete.Text;

    bool r = isDisabled(favoriet);

    if (r) 
        castVote(favoriet);
        // maybe, it would make sense to also notify the user that the vote has been cast
    else
        MessageBox.Show("You have already voted.");
}
```

**6. Use [EntityFramework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)** - in order to avoid the troubles related to handling commands and readers, you can use an ORM to do the dirty work for you.

Comment: You should be careful, your `Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` will throw an exception if no rows has `leerlingnummer = @number`. because `cmd.ExecuteScaler()` will return `DbNull.Value` which is not convertable to `Bool`.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will try this out real soon! I really do appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `bit` Data Type (0 - `false`, 1 - `true`) instead of `int` Data Type in your table. It does exactly what you need and you don't have to use `int` for this.

This means you could change your `validate_disabled` method to use something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT disabled FROM leerling WHERE disabled = 1 AND leerlingnummer = @favoriet";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favoriet", favoriet);
```

I've assumed string `favoriet` is equal to `leerlingnummer` in your table. After you've executed that query, you would simply check if the query contains more than 0 records - if more than 0 records that means the person does not have permission to vote.